# nodejs - jsdom module return isContext() error during require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, jsdom

I can't find any error like this on the web, so I decided to make a post here.

To start off, this is my package.json code

```
{
  "name": "learning_nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "optimist": "~0.6.1",
    "jquery": "~2.1.3",
    "jsdom": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}
```

Next, this is the javascript that I am trying to run in script.js

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv;
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow);
var fs = require('fs');

var file = argv._[0];

var html = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');

console.log(html);
```

And when I go into the directory of both of these files, I run nodejs script.js page.html and that returns this error:

```
daniel@daniel-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs$ nodejs script.js page.html

/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level1/core.js:287
          !vm.isContext(this._ownerDocument._global)) {
              ^
TypeError: Object function Script(code, ctx, filename) {
  if (!(this instanceof Script)) {
    return new Script(code, ctx, filename);
  }

  var ns = new binding.NodeScript(code, ctx, filename);

  // bind all methods to this Script object
  Object.keys(binding.NodeScript.prototype).forEach(function(f) {
    if (typeof binding.NodeScript.prototype[f] === 'function') {
      this[f] = function() {
        if (!(this instanceof Script)) {
          throw new TypeError('invalid call to ' + f);
        }
        return ns[f].apply(ns, arguments);
      };
    }
  }, this);
} has no method 'isContext'
    at Object.core.DOMImplementation._addFeature (/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level1/core.js:287:15)
    at Object.exports.applyDocumentFeatures (/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/documentfeatures.js:45:30)
    at Object.exports.jsdom (/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:62:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/script.js:3:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Also, if it matters, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow` supposed to do, you're not passing anything in, it's generally `jsdom.jsdom(html, options)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Two errors here, and they're both related.

First, I was using nodejs instead of node to run my applications. I'm not sure why but I think that's because of apt-get, so I used nvm to install nodejs and that fixed that problem, but led to another very similar problem.

Apparently jsdom doesn't work with nodejs after jsdom versions 4.0+, so I got an older version and everything is working now.